# T have tried all methods but pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL

Tags: python, ssl, pip, anaconda

After I installed anaconda, I created a virtual environment, but the following error has been displayed:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):
```

I added the system environment variable, and tried all the methods in other posts. pip can only be used in base, and all virtual environments cannot be used.

I would like to know if there are other solutions, this problem did not occur when I used it before.